# curl does not terminate after successful POST

Tags: bash, curl

I have created some curl command to send a POST to my server where I am listening on that port for input to trigger additional action. The command is the following (Just masked the URL):

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"Location\":\"Some Name\",\"Value\":\"40%\"}" http://example.com:8885/
```

I get the following output from curl:

> About to connect() to example.com port 8885 (#0)
>
> Trying 5.147.XXX.XXX...
>
> Connected to example.com (5.147.XXX.XXX) port 8885 (#0)
>
> POST / HTTP/1.1
>
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
>
> Host: example.com:8885
>
> Accept: */*
>
> Content-Type: application/json
>
> Content-Length: 40
>
> upload completely sent off: 40 out of 40 bytes

However after that curl does not close the connection. Am I doing something wrong? Also on the server I only receive the POST as soon as I hit ctrl+c.

Comment: In case somebody else comes up with the same issue, below please find the command that worked for me in the end (Did not manage to send a correct HTTP Response via NodeRed):
<br/>
`BODY="{ \"IrgendeinText\" : \"IrgendeinText\", \"EineAndereProperty\" : \"Noch ein Text usw.\" }"`
<br/>                        
`echo -ne "POST http://example.com:PORT/ HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: example.com:PORT\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: ${#BODY}\r\nAuthorization: Token {API KEY}\r\n\r\n${BODY}" | nc -i 3 example.com PORT`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sits there waiting for the proper HTTP response, and after that has been received it will exit cleanly.

A minimal HTTP/1.1 response could look something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 0
```

... and it needs an extra CRLF after the last header to signal the end of headers.

(and *please* drop the superfluous `-X POST` when you use -d)

Comment: That makes sense, then I just need to find out how to properly send a response from NodeRed, thanks for the hint

Comment: The OP  Posted curl command is all on one line, how does one add an extra CRLF after the last header to signal the end of the headers?

Comment: @zundarz that's a completely different question. But the answer is: you don't need to

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit rusty on this, but according to [section 6.1 of RFC7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-6.1), you might need to add a `Connection: close` header as well. Quoting part of the paragraph:

> The "close" connection option is defined for a sender to signal
> that    this connection will be closed after completion of the
> response.  For    example,
>
> ```
>  Connection: close
> ```
>
> in either the request or the response header fields indicates that
> the sender is going to close the connection after the current
> request/response is complete (Section 6.6).

Let me know if it solves your issue :-)

Comment: No, `Connection: close` just means it will close the connection after its done, but in this case it waits because it isn't done yet...

Comment: dang, too rusty indeed :(

Comment: So how about changing the answer since it is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Is there a question mark in link ?**

I found that my link had question mark like *http... .com/something/something?properties=1* and i tried header **connection: close** but it was still active so i tried then removing *?properties* etc. and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting to [node-red](https://cookbook.nodered.org/http/create-an-http-endpoint) http server (as stated in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45737868/curl-does-not-terminate-after-successful-post#comment78436238_45738607)), do not forget to attach `http response` node.

[image]

I came across the same problem and it seems that `http in` node alone does not close connection.